# Trying to calculate the time an entry was made in Python using the current time and time elapsed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I'm working with a dataset that lists the amount of time that has elapsed since an entry was made in our ERP. It is presented in seconds elapsed (some objects are days old though). I want to create a new column in my table (in format MM:DD:YY HH:SS) that shows the date/time an entry was made by subtracting the number of seconds that have elapsed from the current time. The data type for the 'Time' column is 'M8[ns]'

I looked through various solutions for different pieces (such as converting the entry in my dataframe to be read as seconds) but I'm having some difficulty with my code. Here's what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel (r'File1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype('float64')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit = 's') 
Date Created = (datetime.now () - df['Time'])
df['Date Created'] = Date Created
```

Any insight would be much appreciated

Update:
I made some progress

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel (r'File1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit = 's') 
df['Date Created'] = datetime.now() - df['Time']
```

The Time column is now stored as an int64. Using the new code, ['Time'] is showing:  **1970-01-01 00:02:57**
However only 2:57 has elapsed since created. There are some values that were created days ago. I would like to be able to subtract that 2:57 from the current time to find the date-time the entry was made.

Thank you for the support.

Update 2:
One of my engineers and I were able to figure out a way of determining the date an entry was created.

```
timer = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], unit='s')

#timer = pd.to_datetime(timer)
now = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())

#x = (datetime.now()-datetime(1970,1,1))   #.total_seconds()
#print(timer)
#x = datetime.now()-timer #.total_seconds()
date_created = now-timer
print('Date Created:\n', date_created)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason ['Time'] shows **1970-01-01 00:02:57** is that Unix code starts at 1/1/1970 00:00 (which is equivalent to zero).

I believe your code will work if you convert the two times to integers, and then back to times.

```
df_seconds = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit = 's').astype(int)
df['Date Created'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datetime.now().timestamp()) - df_seconds)
```

Depending on how your spreadsheet works, you may need to play around with `df['Time'].timestamp()` a little, but I think the above code should work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, Reece. I received the following error message when I tried the code:

_AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timestamp'_

Comment: Did you remember to include the brackets at the end of `.timestamp()` both times? timestamp() is a method, not an attribute.

Comment: I did. I tried typing it then did a copy and paste from the code you provided:
`df['Date Created'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datetime.now().timestamp()) - int(df['Time'].timestamp()))`
Am I missing the brackets at another spot?

Comment: No you've entered it right! Perhaps try this instead: `df['Date Created'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(datetime.now().timestamp()) - int(df['Time']))`

If that works I'll amend my answer above.

Comment: Thank you again Reese. I just tried it and came up with the following Error:
_TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>_

I think converting to an integer is the right way, I just can't figure out how. I also tried setting the epoch time to the current time and subtracting the 'Time' column. I got errors that way as well.

Comment: Okay, I believe I've worked it out, you need to change the time to int using astype(). I've modified my answer above, so check if that code works! :)

Comment: Hi Reece, Thank you for the feedback. I worked on this with one of my engineers over the weekend and we were able to solve it:

 `
timer = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], unit='s')

#timer = pd.to_datetime(timer)
now = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())

#x = (datetime.now()-datetime(1970,1,1))   #.total_seconds()
#print(timer)
#x = datetime.now()-timer #.total_seconds()
date_created = now-timer
print('Date Created:\n', date_created)

`
Thank you for all of the help and feedback.